# Jquery tabs href and ID

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, href

I've created a simple tab navigation using css and javascript.
It's working fine altough there is one thing I'd like to clarify.

Each list item (tabs) has an attribute of “href” that matches the ID of the “tab content” div. Then I use jQuery pull off the actions.

Now my question: 
In order to get the ID I use `$(this).find('a').attr('href')` then a simple `show()` to display the appropriate content div.
If I use `$(this).attr('href')` to get ID the `show()` function won't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/eh4eB/

What is the the difference between `$(this).find('a').attr('href')` AND `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 2):

Because your `click` handler is on the `<li>`, `$(this)` is a JQuery wrapper around the `<li>` element. And of course `<li>` elements don't have `href` attributes so there won't be any content in them.

On the other hand, `$(this).find('a')` will give you a JQuery object containing all of the `<a>` elements inside the `<li>` - and the `.attr('href')` will return the `href` attribute from the first of those.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you also using [jQueryUI's Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)? That would be so much easier.

Your code would be just this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#admin-nav" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `click()` event is bound to the `li` elements, so inside the handler `this` is also the `li` element. You therefore need to find the child `a` element before you can determine its `href` attribute.